# Substitute one chain of nodes into anoter chain of nodes in graphdb ? like string substitution

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, redisgraph

Let say I have a chain/list of nodes :

```
 (:node {uid:333})-->(:node {uid:102})-->(:node {uid:155})-->...
```

I want to substitute/replace one or several consecutive nodes with another chain of nodes.

```
 (:node {uid:255})-->(:node {uid:107})
```

it seem to me that the number of operations to achieve this are too many to have them in single query.

```
 1. input [255,107]
 2. create the (255)-->(107)
 3. find the place where to insert in the original chain
 4. connect this node to (255)-->(107)
 5. connect the tail-107 to the original chain (if it does not end)
 6. delete the part to be replaced..
```

the problem is that if it is not single query then it become even more complex.

How would you do this ? (have to  work like string substitution)

One idea to simplify it is to find the positions in the chain and work with indexes .

Answer (score 2):

I hope I've understood your question correctly

```
MATCH ({uid:333})-[]->(s {uid:102})-[e0]->({uid:155})-[e1]->()
CREATE (s)-[:R]->({uid:255})-[:R]->({uid:107})
DELETE e0, e1
```

MATCH will find the chain you would like to modify.

CREATE will introduce the new sub-chain.

DELETE will disconnect the original sub-chain that's being replaced, depending on your use-case you might want to delete the replaced nodes instead of the edges.